# Define custom LocalDB connection for the Identity Framework storage with ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have set up user creation with the `UserStore` and `UserManager` classes, this results in the Identity Framework creating the relevant tables for storing users, claims, etc.

However, these tables are being created automatically in a new LocalDB database called "DefaultConnection", but I wish to modify this, because I already have a separate database and I want the Identity framework to use it for creating these tables.

I can't seem to find any configurations in the solution for this new created database and also, I can't seem to find the newly created "DefaultConnection" connection string as it's not in the Web.config file either.

I can successfully login with the created user via the `UserManager` and `GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn()`, so the Identity framework somehow knows in which database to look for authentication, but yet I don't know where to find these settings.

Is it possible to configure the Identity framework to work with an existing LocalDB database and create the authentication table there in a Web Forms project?

(My project uses Entity Framework v. 6+ model with my existing database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the connection string inside of your Identity DbContext.cs file that gets added to your application by default.

look for this code:

```
public IdentityDbContext()
    : base("Name=SomeDefaultNameConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

in this code change `SomeDefaultNameConnectionString` to whatever the name of the connection string is in your WebConfig to the database you want to use.

Also, I highly recommend this Identity video, Adam Tuliper and Jeremy Foster do a GREAT job of explaining everything about Identity, and they also have a more in depth video series on asp Identity as well.
[Here is the link to the intro video.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/01)